# how to write only one javascript for required field validation for all the textboxes in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

this is my sign up jsp page.

```
 <table align="center">

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Select Category &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="drpdown_name">
                                <option>Select</option>
                                <option>Artist</option>
                                <option>User</option>                        
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Name:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="uname" OnClientClick="return validate();">          
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>
                        Create Password:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="upwd" onclick='validate()'>
                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Confirm Password:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" name="ucpwd" onclick='validate()'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Email-Id:               
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="uemailId" onclick='validate()'>
                        </td>           
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Country:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="ucountry" width="50">
                                <option>India </option>
                                <option>Pakistan</option>
                                <option>Bangladesh</option>
                                <option>Japan</option>
                                <option>Canada</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="login_ml.jsp">Login</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="Submit" value="submit">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

this is my javascript to check the validation of required field

```
    function validate()
{
    var uname = document.getElementsByName("uname").value;
    var upwd = document.getElementsByName("upwd").value;
    var uemailId = document.getElementsByName("uemailId").value;

    if (uname === "")
    {
        alert("Enter First Name");
        return false;
    }

    if (upwd === "") {
        alert("Enter Password");
        return false;
    }

    if (uemailId === "") {
        alert("Enter Email");
        return false;
    }

}
```

When user enters wrong information or may the user leaves a textbox blank, then the client side validation will be work. But I cannot validate the jsp page. infact i think javascript is not even called. what is wrong with this code?

Comment: When you cannot validate the jsp page? I don't think I quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Check this tutorial sample http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: when i click the submit button it should check the uname,pwd,email should  nt be left blank.

Comment: i have checked that one but i just wanted to make onnly one function so i used this one http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/404274/Client-Side-Validation-using-JavaScript

Comment: document.getElementsByName returns a NodeList - a kind of array. So you probably need to get the first element from the nodelist each time - change `var uname = document.getElementsByName("uname").value;` to `var uname = document.getElementsByName("uname")[0].value;`

Comment: thanks all :) for giving your valuable time :) i have solved this, but upwd and ucpwd is not checking.

Answer (score 1):

Fist, `OnClientClick` is not a valid DOM attribute for an input field, so don't use it.

Second, you are using the `onClick` method of each input, but you want the validation to occur after the client enters the information in the input boxes, so you should use `blur` event on each input or `onsubmit` event on the submit button or form (assuming you have a form and a submit button on your HTML).

Third, if you want to use only one function to validate all the fields as required, you can change your input texts to something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="uemailId" onblur='validate(this)'>
```

and then, your `validate` function should be like this:

```
function validate(element) {
  if(element) {
    if(element.value.length == 0) {
      alert("Enter " + element.name);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jsp page

```
<form method="post" action="signup_servlet_ml" name='myForm' onsubmit="return validate()">
                <table align="center">

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Select Category &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="drpdown_name">
                                <option>Select</option>
                                <option>Artist</option>
                                <option>User</option>                        
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Name:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="uname" >          
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <td>
                        Create Password:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="upwd" >
                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Confirm Password:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" name="ucpwd" >
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Email-Id:               
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="uemailId" onclick='validate()'>
                        </td>           
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Country:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="ucountry" width="50">
                                <option>India </option>
                                <option>Pakistan</option>
                                <option>Bangladesh</option>
                                <option>Japan</option>
                                <option>Canada</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="login_ml.jsp">Login</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="Submit" value="submit">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

javascript

```
function validate()
{


    var uname = document.forms["myForm"]["uname"].value;
    var upwd = document.forms["myForm"]["upwd"].value;
    var ucpwd = document.forms["myForm"]["ucpwd"].value;
    var uemailId = document.forms["myForm"]["uemailId"].value;

    if (uname === null || uname === "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    if (upwd === null || upwd === "") {
        alert("password must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    if (upwd === ucpwd)
    {
        alert("Password does not match");
        return false;
    }
    if (uemailId === null || uemailId === "") {
        alert("email must be filled out");
        return false;
    } 
}
```